# Share desktop monitor/keyboard/mouse with laptop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

I have a desktop PC running Windows 7 setup on a traditional desk. From time to time, I would like to plug in a Windows 7 laptop and share the keyboard and mouse, (monitor - I am ok with using the laptop monitor).

What is the easiest way to achieve this? Using a KVM switch? Without needing to reboot either machine?

Thanks

Comment: Good job. I'll remove the comment now...

Answer (score 1):

[Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) is free software that will allow you to share the keyboard and mouse between computers as long as they are on the same network.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there were software solutions to this nowadays. Thanks. I also found an article talking about  this at http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/why-you-no-longer-need-a-kvm-switch-for-your-multi-pc-setup/ Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a KVM will work for what you need. I would suggest one with USB interface so you can "plug-n-play".

[image]